# Non Bridge edges form a cycle in connected graph is equivalent to there exists edge e such that G-e is a tree

Tags: graph-theory

We need to show the following are equivalent:

(1) There exists an edge $e$ of $G$ such that $G−e$ is a tree

(2) $G$ is connected and the set of edges of $G$ which are not bridges form
a cycle

---

This is what I tried:

$\Rightarrow$

We know a tree is a graph that is connected and has no cycles.
So we have $G'=G-e$ is connected & acyclic. Now $G$ & $G'$ has $n$ vertices. We can prove $G'$ has $n-1$ vertices.
Then for $G'$ it has $n$ vertices & $n-1$ edges. Then $G'$ is connected. How do I show if edges of $G$ which are not bridges form a cycles

Also, I have been able to show $(1) => G$ is connected with $V = E$. I know a result where this implies $G$ is connected & has exactly one cycle. (I have been able to prove it)

$\Leftarrow$

$G$ is connected and the set of edges of $G$ which are not bridges form
a cycle. Does this mean $G$ is unicycle? As $G$ is connected by assumption & it forms a cycle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\Leftarrow$

All edges of $G$ that lie in a cycle are not bridges, because if you remove one of them you can still "take the other part of the cycle to get around". Therefore, $G$ has only one cycle $C$, and it contains all of the non-bridges. Removing any edge $e$ from $C$ now destroys the (only) cycle in $G$, which gives an acyclic graph.  The resulting graph is also still connected because we removed a non-bridge.  Therefore $G-e$ is a tree.

$\Rightarrow$

Removing an edge from a non-connected graph cannot make it connected.  Therefore $G$ was connected. Since $G-e$ is connected, $e$ must have been part of a cycle in $G$. Since $G-e$ is a tree, all cycles of $G$ must go through $e$ (otherwise they would still be present in $G-e$).
 Say $e=\{v,w\}$. There exists a unique path $P$ from $v$ to $w$ in $G-e$, since it is a tree. Every edge on $P$ is not a bridge of $G$, because they all lie on the cycle $P\cup e$. If there were more cycles in $G$, then there would be multiple paths from $v$ to $w$ in $G-e$, contradicting that it's a tree. Therefore $P \cup e$ contains *all* the non-bridges.